# How can I look up file name with specific characters

Tags: excel, matlab, select, wolfram-mathematica

I have hundreds of text files with names like: 
`D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1` and `D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 3` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

I would like to select files which name contain `BAPN` as a group and `NOBAPN` as another group. But `BAPN` and `NOBAPN` contain the same characters as `BAPN`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How would you do it if there *wasn't* a common set of characters?  One set of file names contain "NOBAPN" and the other set (contains "BAPN" but *doesn't contain "NOBAPN").

Comment: and you want solutions for excel, matlab, and mathematica?    Show what you have tried in each language or at least clarify what you expect.

Answer (score 5):

Simple regex aughta do what you're looking for:

```
(BAPN)|(NOBAPN)
```

can check it out here - [regex101 BAPN](https://regex101.com/r/5wH4H8/1)

This will capture those exact strings as separate captures without overlapping.

Comment: Useful to know. I have demonstrated the application of this regex in Mathematica in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easy if you can use the hyphen.

```
Select[{"D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1", 
  "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 3"},
 StringMatchQ[#, "*-BAPN*"] &]
```

> ```
> {"D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"}
> ```

Otherwise use `Complement` to obtain the less specific case.

```
stringlist = {
   "D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
   "D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1",
   "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 3",
   "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
   "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"};

posnobapn = Position[stringlist , _?(StringContainsQ[#, "NOBAPN"] &), Heads -> False];
posbapn = Position[stringlist , _?(StringContainsQ[#, "BAPN"] &), Heads -> False];

listbapn = Extract[stringlist , Complement[posbapn, posnobapn]]
```

> ```
> {"D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
>  "D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"}
> ```

```
listnobapn = Extract[stringlist , posnobapn]
```

> ```
> {"D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 3",
>  "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
>  "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"}
> ```

Also, an application of Nieminen's regular expression.

```
regexcases = StringCases[stringlist, RegularExpression["(BAPN)|(NOBAPN)"]];

Pick[stringlist, regexcases /. {"BAPN"} -> True]
```

> ```
> {"D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
>  "D14 J4N4-BAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"}
> ```

```
Pick[stringlist, regexcases /. {"NOBAPN"} -> True]
```

> ```
> {"D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 3",
>  "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 2",
>  "D14 J4N5-NOBAPN_633nm_20x_100%_30accu_10s_point 1"}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use *dir* command to sort the files you want.

To get the file names with BAPN:

```
set1 = dir('*-BAPN*.txt') ;
```

To get the file names with NOBAPN

```
set2 = dir('*-NOBAPN*.txt') ;
```

*set1* and *set2* will be structures.